# Executing different functions based on options selected

Tags: python, button, drop-down-menu, maya

I wanted to know if there is a way of populating a option menu with choices and then each of the different choice gives the build button a different function

for eg:

```
Type = cmds.optionMenu('type',w = 300 ,label = 'Type of crowd:')
cmds.menuItem( label='Walking' )
cmds.menuItem( label='Running' )
cmds.menuItem( label='Cheering' )
cmds.button('Build',command = bld)

def walk(*args):
    print (walking)

def run(*args)
    print (running)

def cheer(*args)
    print (cheer)
```

so if the menu item selected would be walking the  button command would execute the command wak
and if the menu item selected would be running then the button command would execute the command run and so on....
is this even possible in maya python...????

Comment: I don't actually know how to implement this, but you should find a way to pull the `label` from the selected `menuItem`, build a dict of those labels (e.g. `funcdict = {"Walking":walk,"Running":run,"Cheering":cheer}`) and do `funcdict[sel_menu_item](*args)`. As a side note, I renamed your `chr` function to `cheer`-- it's a keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply will try it and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

There's three parts to the problem.

First, you want your options to be callables. I like functools.partial for that, so that you could give the same command different parameters and have it be treated as two different actions:

```
from functools import partial
bigcircle = functools.partial ( cmds.circle, radius = 10)
littleCircle = functools.partial (cmds.circle, radius = 1)
```

the second problem is that menuItems in OptionMenus don't fire their commands directly. They trigger the -cc change command on the owning optionMenu. So we need something that will turn the label back into a callable object. A little class will do:

```
class menuMgr(object):
    '''call the function associated with a key in the **callables dictionary''' 
    def __init__(self, **callables):
        self.Callables = callables

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.Callables[args[-1]]()
```

The third part is to match these with a label. You can do this elegantly with the **kwargs syntax, where you can either pass in a whole dictionary or named keywords:

```
def menu_of_functions(**callables):
    mmgr = menuMgr(**callables)
    Main = cmds.optionMenu('type3',w = 300 ,label = 'Type of crowd:', cc = mmgr)
    for key, partial in callables.items():
        cmds.menuItem(label = key)
    cmds.setParent("..")
```

Heres the whole thing in working form to inspect:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import functools
bigCircle = functools.partial ( cmds.circle, radius = 10)
littleCircle = functools.partial (cmds.circle, radius = 1)

class menuMgr(object):
    def __init__(self, **callables):
        self.Callables = callables

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.Callables[args[-1]]()


def menu_of_functions(**callables):
    mmgr = menuMgr(**callables)
    Main = cmds.optionMenu('type3',w = 300 ,label = 'Type of crowd:', cc = mmgr)
    for key, partial in callables.items():
        cmds.menuItem(label = key)
    cmds.setParent("..") 

q = cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
menu_of_functions(big = bigCircle, small = littleCircle)
cmds.showWindow(q)
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute the commands using a button and not jut by selecting the options..?

Comment: That would just be button(label ="some label here", c=bigCircle).  Partials are great for buttons. button(label="little", c=partial(cmds.button, radius=1)) works too

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, since functions are first class objects in python.

Let's say you have a list of functions.

`fns = [walk, run, cheer]`

1) You'll need a mapping from a string key to the python function.
Let's use a dictionary comprehension.

`options = dict((fn.__name__, fn) for fn in fns)`

Alternatively you can build the dictionary with arbitrary keys.

`options = {"Walking": walk, "Running": run, "Cheering": cheer}`

2) Get a reference to the function by accessing the dictionary item with the functions name.

`options['run'](*args)`

3) ???

4) Profit

Comment: Since he already has menuItems, I recommend he just maps using the labels for the menuItems, e.g. `options = {"Walking":walk, ...}` no reason to map from `fn.__name__` to `fn`

Comment: thats great advice but how would i attach these functions to the command flag of the button...?

Answer (score 0):

Had a chance to do a small bit of research on this today, but I don't actually use Maya     Python so this may not be viable code -- at least it should be close!

```
def walk(*args):
    print ("walking")

def run(*args)
    print ("running")

def cheer(*args)
    print ("cheer")

fncdict = {"Walking":walk,"Running":run,"Cheering":cheer}

def dofunc(funcname):
    try: fncdict[funcname]()
    except KeyError: print("adsmith doesn't really know how this crap works,
                           and gave you some really shoddy advice. Go downvote
                           his answer.")

Type = cmds.optionMenu('type',w = 300 ,label = 'Type of crowd:')
# Please don't name things this way! naming conventions in PEP 8
#  make this look like a class not an instance of optionMenu
cmds.menuItem( label='Walking', parent = Type )
cmds.menuItem( label='Running', parent = Type )
cmds.menuItem( label='Cheering', parent = Type )

cmds.button('Build',command = lambda x: dofunc(Type.value))
# I'm assuming this is the button you want to use to say "GO", right?
```

From the little I've read, it looks like `optionMenu.value` refers to the text in the active `menuItem`, but I can't say for sure -- it may just be the text for that `optionMenu` in which case the button will call `dofunc('Type of crowd:')` which will return the exception I built to shame myself.

Here's an alternative that I KNOW will work, but it's ugly and unnecessary.

```
# all
# those
# functions
# go
# here
# including
# the dict and dofunc

activeMenuItem = None

Type = cmds.optionMenu('type',w = 300 ,label = 'Type of crowd:',
                       changeCommand = lambda x: activeMenuItem = x)
#  this fails because you can't do assignments in a lambda -- OOPS!!

cmds.menuItem( label='Walking', parent = Type )
cmds.menuItem( label='Running', parent = Type )
cmds.menuItem( label='Cheering', parent = Type )

cmds.button('Build',command = lambda x: dofunc(activeMenuItem))
```

The `changeCommand` option in `optionMenu` gets called every time you change items. I've assigned it to a [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) that updates the variable `activeMenuItem` to the value in the newly-active `menuItem`, then had the button reference the variable instead of querying the `optionMenu` for its currently selected button, but let's be honest -- this is what menus are MADE to do. There is DEFINITELY a way to do it without storing every single selection.

EDIT: THIS LAST ONE WON'T WORK BECAUSE YOU CAN'T DO ASSIGNMENTS WITHIN LAMBDA EXPRESSIONS. MY FAULT!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but Type = cmds.optionMenu('type',w = 300 ,label = 'Type of crowd:',
                       changeCommand = lambda x: activeMenuItem = x)is giving me a syntax error!!! is there some other way..? as i can query the text in the menu item by using cmds.optionMenu('Type',q=True,v=True) would that help i tried doing this     cmds.button('Build',label = 'Build' ,w = 300,h = 50,bgc = (0,1,0), actOnPress = True,command = cmds.optionMenu('Type',q=True,v=True) )  but it did not work

Comment: Oh shoot you can't do assignment within a lambda, that's right. Not sure then -- you'll have to consult your documentation since I've never worked with this implementation of Python before. Sorry!

Comment: @Arnvfx if I told you to write me code that returned the `label` attribute of the active `menuItem` -- how would you write that?

Comment: Type = cmds.optionMenu('Type',w = 300 ,label = 'Type of crowd')
cmds.menuItem(label='build',parent = Type)
cmds.menuItem(label='buildtest' ,parent = Type)
cmds.menuItem( label='Cheering',parent = Type)
option = cmds.optionMenu('Type',q=True,v=True)
print cmds.optionMenu('Type',q=True,v=True)

Comment: what's `option` in this code? Literally run it and find out :P

Comment: option = cmds.optionMenu('Type',q=True,v=True)        if u run print option it will return back the value of the label but does not update when u change the value in the option menu

Comment: The value of WHICH label? Be specific. You said it doesn't update when you change the value in the option menu, so it checks it when you define option and never again? That's not a problem.... Build your dictionary like before (`fncdict = {"Walking":walk,"Running":run,"Cheering":cheer}`) then for your `build` button, use `command= lambda x: fncdict[cmds.optionMenu('Type',q=True,v=True)]()`. I find it really hard to believe this is actually how it's done, but let me know if it works anyway....

Comment: Sorry,This does not work either,it still gives me the error invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I have kind of figured out an easier way to this problem 
    cmds.optionMenu('Greetings',Label = 'Greet')
    cmds.menuItem(label= hi,parent = 'Greetings)
    cmds.menuItem(label = Hello,parent = 'Greetings')

def Greet(*args)
    menuItems = cmds.optionMenu('Greetings',q=True,v=True)
    if menuItems = hi
       print "hi"
    menuItemsnew = cmds.optionMenu('Greetings',q=True,v=True)
    if  menuItemsnew = hello
        print "hello"

This should work,it worked for me